# moving axis-labels in a matlab2tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab2tikz

I'm working with matlab2tikz to make pictures for a paper I have to write. I need a pretty small picture because I'm putting two of them together, each of the two consisting of 2 subplots in Matlab.
At first all my axis labels and my legend covered my whole graph so I found how to make them smaller, now my pictures look okay except that my y-axis labels are not where they should be. They overlap with the other graphs. This is what it looks like right now:

[image: my graphs]

This is the code I use to export the pictures from Matlab:

```
    matlab2tikz('height','5cm','width','7cm','extraaxisoptions',['title style {font=\small},'...
                   'xlabel style={font=\tiny},'...
                   'ylabel style={font=\tiny},',...
                   'legend style={font=\tiny},',...
                   'ticklabel style={font=\tiny}'])
```

And this is the code I used to put it in my latex-file:

```
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \input{RkleinerGamma1.tex} 
    \subcaption*{$\gamma = 1$}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \input{RkleinerGamma01.tex} 
    \subcaption*{$\gamma = 0.1$}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{tijdsverloop van de populaties}
    \end{figure}
```

So now my question: Can anybody tell me how to get my y-labels closer to my axes, or maybe how to get my graphs further away from eachother so the overlap isn't there?

Comment: You could try add the either of the following to the `ylabel style` key: `ylabel near ticks`, or `ylabel shift={<dim>}` where `<dim>` is something like `5pt`.

Comment: @HerrK. 
 
Both of the commands don't give an error in Matlab, but when I compile my Latex file it says with the 'near ticks' command that it doesn't know the key and with the shift command it say 'Cannot parse this coordinate' Any idea what to do about this?

Comment: You misunderstood him, those commands  are for `pgfplots`, the LaTeX package that actually draws the plots. His point was that you should try editing the `.tex` file produced by `matlab2tikz`. We could help you edit that, but to do so we need to see the code. Hence, if you're still wondering about this, please edit your question to include the content of `RkleinerGamma01.tex`.

Comment: You can use Herr K.'s suggestion of adding a `ylabel style` key directly from matlab by passing the argument to matlab2tikz: `matlab2tikz(...,'extraAxisOptions','ylabel shift={-5pt}')`